# To show the details of a file/folder like size,type,hidden or not,permissins etc all together

Tags: android

i want to show the details of the file or folder after selecting that.
eg.Long press on a file say "icon.jpg" and we have some info like size,type,dateTime Modified,last opened,
hidden or not,permissions etc.
please help me by some example.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Jokes apart. You need to create your own [file browser](http://code.google.com/p/anddos/source/browse/trunk/anddos/src/com/si/anddos/filechooser/?r=105). Also read about [creating context menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)